# Cannot load the application in newer version without loading it in older version of Angular

Tags: angular, loading, angular-errorhandler

I was working on angular 2 previously and now upgraded the application to angular 12, the application is loading but only if the  version 2 is compiled and loaded. It is compiling successfully , but giving errors in console.

How can I load the newer version of application?

Comment: It's compiling successfully... In which version?

Comment: use [update guide](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: @AmitKumar Yes, its compiled successfully, the older version was 2 and newer is 12

Comment: you can solve each error one by one after updating to 12!  However, Angular cli handles the upgrading itself in most cases. But i have seen those happening in consecutive update version (especially from 12 to 13 then 13 to 14). So, you can try to update one version at a time. Don't upgrade to 12 directly!!

Answer (score 0):

Angular update guide says specificaly not to update multiple versions at once.
Try to update and solve any issues one version at a time.